# Setar como padrão o Usuario logado no model | Django + Python3

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-admin

estou tentando aprender Django, e com isso estou tentando criar um sisteminha simples de tickets.

Eu avancei bastante nos meus estudos, mas agora empaquei no seguinte problema.

Como fazer por padrão ao salvar um Ticket, que o Django salve o usuário logado atualmente?

Segue meus códigos do arquivo `models.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime

class Projeto(models.Model):
    """
        Classe que gere os Projetos
        Permite que se cadastre N usuários por Projeto
        Retorna:
            NOME_DO_PROJETO | SITE_DO_PROJETO
    """
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    site = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    informacoes = models.TextField(blank=True)
    usuarios = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='projetos')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome + " | " + self.site

class Ticket(models.Model):
    """
        Classe que gere os Tickets no sistema.
        Retorna:
            DATA HORA | TITULO DO CHAMADO
    """
    TIPOS_TICKET = (
        ('BUG', 'Bug'),
        ('URGENTE', 'Urgente'),
        ('FINANCEIRO', 'Financeiro'),
        ('MELHORIA', 'Melhoria')
    )
    STATUS_TICKET = (
        ('ABERTO', 'Aberto'),
        ('AGUARDANDO_CLIENTE', 'Aguardando Cliente'),
        ('EM_ANALISE', 'Em Análise'),
        ('FINALIZADO', 'Finalizado'),
        ('CANCELADO', 'Cancelado'),
    )
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    conteudo = models.TextField()
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TIPOS_TICKET, default='BUG')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS_TICKET, default='ABERTO')
    projeto = models.ForeignKey(
        Projeto,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'usuarios':1}
    )
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )
    data_abertura = models.DateTimeField('Data Abertura', auto_now_add=True)
    data_fechamento = models.DateTimeField('Data Fechamento', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(datetime.strftime(self.data_abertura, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M") + " | " + self.titulo)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.usuario = User
        super(Ticket, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

class TicketMsg(models.Model):
    """
        Mensagens dos tickets
        Retorna:
            texto da mensagem
    """
    texto = models.TextField()
    ticket = models.ForeignKey(Ticket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data_resposta = models.DateTimeField('Data Resposta')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.texto)
```

E meu arquivo `admin.py`

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Ticket, TicketMsg, Projeto

# Register your models here.
class ProjetoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Projeto
    filter_horizontal = ('usuarios',)

class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Ticket
    exclude = ('status', 'data_fechamento', 'data_abertura', 'usuario')
    list_display = ('titulo', 'tipo', 'status', 'projeto', 'data_abertura')
    list_filter = ('projeto', 'tipo', 'status')

    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return ['data_abertura']

admin.site.register(Projeto, ProjetoAdmin)
admin.site.register(Ticket, TicketAdmin)
admin.site.register(TicketMsg)
```

Este é o resultado até agora da listagem, usando o ADMIN do Django

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A idéia é que quando a pessoa digite um ticket, o sistema identifique qual usuário o fez.

Já consegui fazer o sistema filtar quais projetos um usuário tem direito de abrir ticket para.

Agora falta o sistema gravar o ID do Usuário logado pra que eu consiga identificar QUEM abriu o ticket.

Segue imagem do form:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Toda ajuda é bem vinda! 
Obrigado pessoal!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Existe um metodo chamado `.save_model` no ModelAdmin que tem o objetivo de fazer pre e post save operações.

```
class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
...

def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    obj.user = request.user
    super(ArticleAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Mais detallhes na documentação [ModelAdmin.save_model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model).

Answer (score 0):

Outra solução que tipicamente utilizo é criar uma classe "abstract", que implementa a lógica típica de gravar o user que criou o registo ou que atualizou o registo, mas aqui adaptado ao teu caso:

**Para o teu exemplo, crias um ficheiro common.py:**

**common.py**

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models
from django.utils.timezone import now
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from ai.middleware.current_user import CurrentUserMiddleware
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericRelation

class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    usuario = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name=_("Usuário"), blank=True, null=True,
                                   related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_created", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, editable=False)

    @staticmethod
    def get_current_user():
        """
        Get the currently logged in user over middleware.
        Can be overwritten to use e.g. other middleware or additional functionality.
        :return: user instance
        """
        return CurrentUserMiddleware.get_current_user()

    def set_user_fields(self, user):
        """
        Set user-related fields before saving the instance.
        If no user with primary key is given the fields are not set.
        :param user: user instance of current user
        """
        if user and user.pk:
            if not self.pk:
                self.usuario = user
            else:
                self.usuario = user

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        current_user = self.get_current_user()
        self.set_user_fields(current_user)
        super(CommonInfo, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

No teu models alteras de forma a utilizares a classe abstract:

**models.py**

```
from yourapp.common import CommonInfo

class Ticket(CommonInfo): # trocas models.Model por CommonInfo, que já herda de models.Model
    """
        Classe que gere os Tickets no sistema.
        Retorna:
            DATA HORA | TITULO DO CHAMADO
    """
    TIPOS_TICKET = (
        ('BUG', 'Bug'),
        ('URGENTE', 'Urgente'),
        ('FINANCEIRO', 'Financeiro'),
        ('MELHORIA', 'Melhoria')
    )
    STATUS_TICKET = (
        ('ABERTO', 'Aberto'),
        ('AGUARDANDO_CLIENTE', 'Aguardando Cliente'),
        ('EM_ANALISE', 'Em Análise'),
        ('FINALIZADO', 'Finalizado'),
        ('CANCELADO', 'Cancelado'),
    )
    titulo = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    conteudo = models.TextField()
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=TIPOS_TICKET, default='BUG')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=STATUS_TICKET, default='ABERTO')
    projeto = models.ForeignKey(
        Projeto,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'usuarios':1}
    )
    # usuario = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) # removes esta linha, uma vez que herda da classe CommonInfo
    data_abertura = models.DateTimeField('Data Abertura', auto_now_add=True)
    data_fechamento = models.DateTimeField('Data Fechamento', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(datetime.strftime(self.data_abertura, "%d/%m/%y %H:%M") + " | " + self.titulo)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # self.usuario = User deixa de ser necessário esta linha uma vez que já grava na classe abstract
        super(Ticket, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```